# How to replace all even elements in an integer array with a special symbol '$' using java

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

We have an integer array and all even numbers in that array must be replaced by "$";

Here is my code :

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
char specialChar = '$';

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
array[i] = specialChar;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output Obtained : [1, 42, 3, 42, 5, 42]
Expected Output : [1, $, 3, $, 5, $]

Comment: You simply can't put a value that is not an `int` inside an array of `int`s. So are you sure you're not meant to print the array one element at a time and print a $ for even-indexed elements instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to switch the result array into char array

```java
char specialChar = '$';
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
char[] result = new char[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        result[i] = specialChar;
    } else {
        result[i] = (char)(array[i] + '0');
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: `char[] result = new char[array.length]();` should not have parentheses at the end, otherwise correct

Comment: Another solution which might be easier would be to print each value in the for loop unless it is even, in which case you would print $, but then it doesn't print as nicely with the braces and comma separators, unless you add them in print statements

Comment: yes you could just print instead of creating a new array